# probability word problems

Tags: probability

A college Calculus 1 course with 15 (20) who have (had) some(none) calculus in high school & probability of 3/10 (1/10) of making an "A" in Calculus 1. Some student earns "A", what is the probability of said student had some calculus in high school?

Answer (score 2):

What information do we have?

```
P(Had Calc) = 15/35
P(Gets A | Had Calc) = 3/10
P(Gets A | Not Had Calc) = 1/10
```

So we can use `P(A|B) = P(B|A)*P(A)/P(B)` like so:

```
P(Had Calc | Gets A) = P(Gets A | Had Calc) * P(Had Calc) / P(Gets A)
```

We still need `P(Gets A)`, but I'm sure you can figure that out.

Comment: Do you mind walking me thru this problem to make sure I got the correct answer?